# What does the Middle English "un" ending mean?

Tags: middle-english

As I understood the Middle English "un" ending means possessive Pronouns ([ourun](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=houn&search_form_type=general&q1=ourun&s=0&t1=en_wyc&ns=0)), third-person plural past participle ([fallun](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=ourun&search_form_type=general&q1=fallun&s=0&t1=en_wyc&ns=0), comun, wonnun) or having the quality of ([wollun](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=eirun&search_form_type=general&q1=wollun&s=0&t1=en_wyc&ns=0), lynun, goldun, stonun).

Why "un" ending are used in Middle English "eirun" eggs?

[Wycliffe's Bible](https://www.originalbibles.com/wycliffe-bible-new-testament-1400-pdf/)
Job.39:14
[Studylight:](https://www.studylight.org/desk/index.cgi?sr=0&old_q=eirun&search_form_type=general&q1=Job%2039%3A14&s=0&t1=en_wyc&ns=0)
"which ostrige forsakith hise eirun in the erthe, in hap thou schalt make tho hoot in the dust"

King James Bible:

"Which leaveth her eggs in the earth, and warmeth them in dust…"

Comment: Are you asking about 'eirun'? Please make that clear and also give what you've found already about the meaning of it in Modern English (and it's etymology).

Comment: ['Eirun' It's probably  an alternate speling of 'eiren' = eggs](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED13109/track?counter=2&search_id=1204160) the '-en' is simply the more common germanic plural ending.